# Confirm if application is using nginx to serve static files

Tags: python, nginx, flask, webserver, gunicorn

I am using this [tutorial - part 1](https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/), but i am not sure how to test if the app is running with nginx serving static files or not.

I have exactly the same code.

---

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/flask_project

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask_project/static/;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8000
```

All routes are working fine. However if I do `http://localhost:8000/static` i will see

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

And apparently I should see the page with `<h1>Test!</h1>` from static folder.

What i am doing wrong?

Basically i want to know how configure nginx to serve static files and then confirm.

```
-app.py
-static
   -index.html
```

Comment: Your requests to `localhost:8000` goes directly to gunicorn bypassing nginx completely. You should request `localhost/...` or whatever name you use for server.

Comment: @AlexeyTen so, i am serving static files correctly or not? That's the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, requests to port `8000` completely bypass nginx, so nothing strange here. You should go to `localhost` without port number.

Second, you have to symlink this config to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and reload nginx.

Third, your static location is wrong. You have `location` without trailing slash and `alias` with one. They should always be with or without trailing slash simultaneously. And in this case it's even better to have `root` directive.

```
server {
    root /home/www/flask_project;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /static/ {
        # empty. Will serve static files from ROOT/static.
    }
}
```

Comment: if i run gunicorn in the port 8000, why should i go to the localhost without the port? Basically you are saying the tutorial is wrong after thousands of views? Anyway, i am having the same output with your answer.

Comment: This is from tutorial `Open your browser and navigate to http://your_domain_name_or_ip_address.` No port, you see.
And, yes, this tutorial is written by someone who barely knew nginx.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand. localhost will use the port 80 by default. I am saying explicitly to use 8000 in gunicorn. If i go to localhost i will get This webpage is not available

Comment: Port 80 goes to nginx. Anything it doesn't know how to serve directly, it hands off to gunicorn. When you go to port 8000, you bypass nginx and go directly to gunicorn. If you want to test that nginx is working, you need to send your request through it by using port 80.

Answer (score -1):

You should make request directly http://localhost:8000/static/index.html then you will see response.

But if you want to see on `index.html` by default, you should have something like in conf:

```
location /static {
    alias  /home/www/flask_project/static/;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html index.html;
}
```

Comment: In that case, I will see the response even with the nginx stopped. The problem is how check if nginx is working or not.

Comment: Nope, you won't see the response if the nginx has been stopped.